# C - How to use macro to leave out assert()'s in production release

Tags: c

my question might be partially related to [When should we use asserts in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114008/when-should-we-use-asserts-in-c) But I'm still wondering which would be a better practice when I have a project with a bunch of assertions spread out at places:

Do I use the DNDEBUG flag to turn asserts into no-ops (as suggested in the related question), or do I surround all the asserts with a if macro like

```
#ifdef TEST
#include <assert.h>
#endif

....

#ifdef TEST
    assert(...);
#endif

....
```

and use a -D TEST option at compliation time? Is there some sort of standard or 'convention' on this? I feel like the latter would be neater.. 
Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there already a macro which disables assertions?

Comment: Maybe NDEBUG, por favor?

Comment: Does it remove the assert.h though?

Comment: @michael.z No, and there's no need to.

Comment: Probably not, as `assert` still has to be defined to be a no-op then. But why would that be a problem? It's just a couple of lines, every compiler worth using blazed through that in no time.

Comment: NDEBUG is recognized by <assert.h>. That's the whole point of it :)

Comment: @nos Why is that? I thought include always adds size to the executable unless the header's been included before..?

Comment: @michael.z: what makes you think that?

Comment: @larsmans Not sure to be honest.. I just think since the preprocessor replaces #include with the file content, that might be the case?

Comment: @michael.z: yes, that's right. But `<assert.h>` and other well-behaved header files only contain macro expansions and declarations, i.e. things that only matter at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some sort of standard or 'convention' on this?

Yes: define `NDEBUG` in production code. It's the ISO C standard way of doing this and only adds a few milliseconds to your compile cycle (or saves some compared to not defining `NDEBUG`, as you're including it anyway) because the compiler/preprocessor has to scan through `<assert.h>` to find out it has to remove things from your code. It doesn't bloat your executable or add any other kind of runtime overhead, unless you do crazy things in a `#ifndef NDEBUG` block.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized I misread your comment above lol

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do this.  Discussion below the code.

In some .h file:

```
#define PASS ((void)0)

extern void hook(void);
extern void asserthook(void);

#ifdef DEBUG
#define ENABLE_ASSERTS
#endif // DEBUG

#ifdef ENABLE_ASSERTS
#define AssertMesg(expr, mesg) \
    do { \
        if (!(expr)) \
        { \
            asserthook(); \
            fprintf(streamErr, \
                    "%s(%d): assertion failed: ", __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(streamErr, "%s\n", mesg); \
            fflush(streamErr); \
            Exit(10); \
        } \
    } while (0)
#define Assert(expr)  AssertMesg(expr, "")

#else // !ENABLE_ASSERTS

#define AssertMesg(expr, mesg)  PASS
#define Assert(expr)  PASS

#endif // !ENABLE_ASSERTS
```

And in some .c file:

```
void hook(void)
{
    PASS;
}

void asserthook(void)
{
    hook();
}
```

First of all, my asserts always call `asserthook()` which calls `hook()`.  These functions are just places to set a breakpoint; I also have `errhook()` that is called for an error.  Usually I just set a breakpoint on `hook()` itself, and then anytime my code is taken down by an assert, I have the debugger stopped right on the error with the stack backtrace in just the spot I need.

When you are trying to make a multiline macro that will act like a C statement, the usual way to do it is to put it in curly braces and then wrap those braces in `do` / `while (0)`.  That's a loop that executes a single time, so it's really not a loop.  But wrapping it like that means it is a statement and when you put a semi-colon on the line to terminate the statement, it's actually correct.  Thus code like this will compile without errors and do the right thing:

```
if (error)
    AssertMesg(0, "we have an error here");
else
    printf("We don't have an error after all.\n");
```

If you didn't do the silly `do` / `while (0)` wrapper, and just had the curly braces, the above code won't work!  First, the compiler would wonder why you have a `;` right after a curly brace and before an `else`; second, the `else` would associate with the hidden `if` inside the `AssertMesg()` macro, and the `printf()` would never be called.  You could fix the latter problem with explicit curly braces but it is clearly better to set up your macro so that it works in all situations, and that is what the `do` / `while (0)` does for you.

`(void)0` is my preferred do-nothing statement.  You could just use `do {} while (0)` if you prefer, or anything else that has no side-effects and doesn't use any variables.

The worst thing about the `do` / `while (0)` trick is that you sometimes see error messages that are complaining about a `do` loop, and since it's hidden inside macros you need to remember what is really going on.  But it's the best way I know to make multiline macros work correctly.

When possible, you should use static inline functions rather than macros.  But macros are completely portable to even sucky lame C compilers, and you need to use a macro for an assert so you can have `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` expanded properly.

(You could write a varargs function that does the actual assert, and then just make a macro that expands to a single call to that function, as long as varargs work correctly on all the compilers you use.  I think I could do that now, but I already have the multiline macro solution working and I haven't touched it in a long time.)