# Using strlen and asserts together in C

Tags: c, assert, c-strings, strlen

I understand that we want to use `assert` when we want to check for impossible case. In a book I have, I saw the following two examples:

```
void foo(char* str) { assert ((str+strlen(str)) != NULL); }
void bar(char* str) { assert (str[strlen(str)] != NULL); }
```

I'm trying to figure out if they are valid checks. As I understand the first example is not valid because we check if the address is `NULL` and that is not right. But I'm not sure what we are checking in the second example. I'm having hard time understanding when its the right time to use `assert`. I understand the explanation of "checking impossible cases" but it a bit different for each case.

**EDIT**: Is there a diffrence between the functions I showed before and those?:

```
void foo(char* str) { assert (!(str+strlen(str))}
void bar(char* str) { assert (! str[strlen(str)]); }
```

Comment: Your book isn't very good.  You're right, `str+strlen(str)` pretty much can't be NULL, that's sort of like saying `assert(1 + 1 != 3)`.  And for a valid string, `str[strlen(str)]` is guaranteed to be the null character, `'\0'`, although that's *not* the same as a `NULL` pointer constant, so this is even more confused.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114008) for some better advice on using `assert`.

Comment: This may be considered nitpicking but "checking impossible cases" are not what asserts are for. If the case is impossible, there is no need for checking it. For instances you would never make an assert checking that an unsigned int is >= zero. Asserts are for checking possible but invalid/illegal cases.

Comment: Get another book...

Comment: I hope you have a fireplace :D

Answer (score 3):

The second one is kind of strange.  I think what your book might have been trying to show is that all c strings need to end in a null/zero character.  However, the way strlen works is that it will keep scanning the string until it finds a null character.  Therefore in the seconds case it will either find a null character or you will get a segmentation fault when it reads invalid memory and your program will crash.  So basically there is no point to the assert because it will either pass or the program will crash.

Actually the first one suffers from the same problem as well.  Because even if a null pointer is passed to foo the strlen of a null pointer will likely result in a crash.  It would make more sense to `assert(str != NULL)`.

Comment: Isn't that true for both cases?

Answer (score 2):

Neither expression makes sense.

In the first expression

```
assert ((str+strlen(str)) != NULL);
```

there is a check whether the address of the terminating zero character `'\0'` of a string is equal to NULL. It is evident that it is always unequal to NULL.

From the C Standard (6.5.6 Additive operators)

> 8. ... In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array 
>      object, the expressions (P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and
>      (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i+n-th and
>      i−n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist.

In the second expression

```
assert (str[strlen(str)] != NULL)
```

there is a check whether the terminating zero character `'\0'` is equal to a null-pointer. This also does not make sense.

Pay attention to that the above expression is equivalent to the following expression

```
assert (*(str+strlen(str)) != NULL);
```

and hence also does not make sense.

Comment: For the second expression, will it be more logical to use `assert (*(str+strlen(str)) != NULL);`? Is it a valid check?

Comment: @vesii It is an invalid expression because it is equivalent to the second expression. It is unclear what you are trying to check.

Comment: It took from a book. Is the first expression is the same as `assert (!str+strlen(str))`?

Comment: @vesii No, they are not the same. In the last expression there is applied the negation operator though the expression also does not make sense.

Comment: Is it possible to add in your answer about those two expressions I have added in the edit?

Comment: @vesii I already added one of your expression referenced in comments to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(char* str) { assert ((str+strlen(str)) != NULL); }
```

is legal C-code but the expression `(str+strlen(str)) != NULL` will always be true so there is no point in making an assert.

```
void bar(char* str) { assert (str[strlen(str)] != NULL); }
```

is comparing a pointer with a char (aka interger type). That makes no sense.

```
void foo(char* str) { assert (!(str+strlen(str)));}
```

is the same as the first `foo` (notice that I fixed the syntax error)

```
void bar(char* str) { assert (! str[strlen(str)]); }
```

is different from the first `bar`. This is legal code. It is the same as `assert (str[strlen(str)] == 0);`. However, it makes no sense to have this assert as it can never fail.

Notice that asserts are **not** for checking something that are impossible! Asserts are for checking something that are possible but invalid/illegal.